# Is it possible to give recyclerview a dynamic template?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Like for example I create a view

```
LinearLayout rowTemplate = new LinearLayout(getContext());
```

Then in the viewholder of the recycler i attempt to do the following

```
return new TransactionViewHolder(rowTemplate);
```

Can this work ? . Normally we do the following

```
return new TransactionViewHolder(((RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.employee_item, parent, false)));
```

I am unsure how would I inflate the view in such a manner that the RV also can attach this rowtemplate into itself. I actually am planning to do something like this and thought to ask if anyone has any hints on this

Comment: Can it work?  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: No it didnt.  But there was a pretty easy workaround.

Comment: Inflate an empty item layout with just a root.  Make a new overload of the viewholder constructor that takes this dynamic view along with the inflated view. Then in the constructor say inflatedview.addview(dynamicview) . Id post the code as an answer of you'd like

Comment: That would be good and then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Well it wont work without the inflater.inflate(viewResource,parent, false). The reason being that even though we have a view already created , it would be an orphan floating around in the RV , since we haven't attached it to the RV's parent.

Here is a good workaround which keeps intact the RVs recycling as well as exhibits the desired behavior

```
   // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                  int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    if (viewType == TYPE_TRANSACTION) {
        return new TransactionViewHolder(((RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.transaction_item, parent, false)), ((LinearLayout) createRowTemplate(templateTransaction)));
    } else {
        return new LoadHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.load_item, parent, false));
    }
}
```

In the TransactionViewHolder constructor do the following.

```
   public TransactionViewHolder(RelativeLayout rowRootView, LinearLayout rowTemplate) {
            super(rowRootView);
            this.rowRootView = rowRootView;
            this.rowRootView.addView(rowTemplate);

            rowRootView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
```